# When using social auth, how to differentiate newly registered user from registered users in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

For email registration, firebase has two different methods i.e. `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` and `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`.
`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` can be used for registration phase.
`signInWithEmailAndPassword` can be used with registered user for authentication.

But with social auth, `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)` and `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` methods are supported.
There seems to be no way to differentiate between new users and already registered users.

How this should be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only way to do so is to use realtime database and save the user when they first sign in and set some flag. The next time the user signs in, if the user and the flag is set then the user is previously registered.

Comment: This looks like workaround. Firebase should give method to support this functionality. I will raise ticket with them.

Comment: As per firebase-support, this feature may require design changes, hence may not be available in near future.